# Excel VBA connect to Excel application in Citrix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

I have been wondering how (and if) I can connect my local Excel to the Citrix version of Excel through VBA.

**Background**

We’re making budgets for our franchisees and stores, and in this process we’re using a lot of data output from our BI-system. The copy and paste process is very time consuming. We’ve found out that instead of using 10-15 different reports, we can manage by using 1 report with 10-15 different tables, and it will export into 1 workbook with 10-15 different sheets (one for each table). This export is made to the Citrix application of Excel.

**What I need to do**

I want to connect my local excel to the only workbook I have open through Citrix. I’m not sure if I need to create a gateway somehow through Citrix, or if it’s possible to recognize the open workbook without a gateway connection. If I’m able to connect to this workbook, everything else is fairly easy to make.

**The question**

Is it possible to make a connection between these two different Excel applications? If so, how should I start?

I tried using ActiveWindow, but since it’s not in the same application, it didn’t recognize it of course...

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you save the citrix excel workbook to a shared network server folder that you can access in both places?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but not the most desirable solution. Otherwise we would be looking at a solution, where we can download the BI-system on our computer locally :)

Comment: you just need the file that BI system creates. not the system itself. from your original question anyway, sounds like you just need to access the Excel file. that should be very easy by storing/saving to a shared location.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman reason I said we wanted the system, is that it will open as an excel-file on our desktop, instead of the Citrix/Remote Desktop :)